# Unity5 terrain built in material too "glossy"

Tags: shader, unity-game-engine, terrain

Hi guys I've a little problem with the unity built in terrain shader. I've created a simple a scene but I've a lot of reflection and glowing on the terrain without a reason.

I didn't change anything in lights or whatever comes to default in a unity scene.
That's some screens:

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Try asking this in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could check if you imported normal maps correctly and if the metallic and smoothness values of your terrain textures are at zero.

Comment: how can i check that ? it's the standard built in terrain

Answer (score 0):

Edit each texture inside terrain drawing tab, change their Smoothness and Metallic parameters.
or
Create custom Material (from Nature/Terrain shader) and use custom for this terrain.